# How to call a local WCF service?

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm creating a test component for my application and would like to test the wcf service endpoints to ensure that they're up and working. I'm planning to call the service with dummy data to check if it's working. I need the following:
1. Is there a better way than using dummy data?
2. How to call a local service? Can I use the HttpWebRequest to post data to it by providing relative path? Or else, can I add a service reference using relative path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a `Ping` or `Echo` method.

I would just add a service reference to your test component to your service.

Comment: You have to give it a full qualified path, but you can set it to be settable from the config.

Comment: +1 for the insights. But it puts me in a bit of trouble. Is there any other way to effectively call the wcf service.

Comment: Well, I don't know in advance the URL of my application so for a full qualified path I'll need to change that.